# Calculate Leaderboard Ranking and Point System for Users in React Js Javascript MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mern

I am creating a **MERN Stack Application** which gives **'Points'** to a **User** based on how many Posts, Comments and Likes they do.

I need to generate a **LEADERBOARD** from this, that **Ranks all the Users** (User with the most Posts, Comments & Likes) and also shows the sum count of Post, Comments & Likes.

Currently I have a userSchema as per below:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const { Schema } = mongoose

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
 
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        content: 'String', 
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
      },
    ],
    likes: [
          {
            user: {
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: 'User',
            },
          },
        ],

      }
    );
```

How do I list out in a **LEADERBOARD** all the **Users and Rank them based on their TOTAL POINTS** (sum of number of posts, comments & likes)?

Comment: That's a lot of calculations since you need to potentially retrieve all the posts each time to check if their comments and likes are owned by a certain user.
I think you could optimize it byt creating separate models for `likes` and `comments` giving them a ref to the post and to the user owner.
This way it's much easier to make a query and retrieve all posts, likes, comments of a certain user.
Using mongo and mongoose, I found out it's highly suggested to keep the schemas structure as flatter as possible and to relationate models through refs. My 2 cents.

Comment: Not familiar with mongo, but an approach that may be applied is to add a `pointsSummary` to the `User` entity and use a transaction every time a Post, Comment or Like is added or removed to update those entities along with `pointsSummary`. Then create an index on `pointsSummary` and you should have your leaderboard.